# HTML5 audio and video recording using WebRTC in Android Firefox browser does not record video

Tags: android, firefox, webrtc, recording

I'm doing `webRTC` audio and video recording in android devices using `MediaStreamRecorder.js` into a `webm file`.

I'm using `firefox (version 39)` browser to get audio video in a single webm. I'm using `indexedDB` to save the recorded file locally.

While playing only audio is playing, video is not recorded. The same setup  records audio and video perfectly in desktop. I'm getting this issue only in android devices. I don't know in which portion i'm doing wrong.

I googled and gathered some info saying - latest Android OS devices support audio/video `codec in VP8` and `Vorbis codecs`. I'm doing recording in `VP8` and `Opus codec`.

Is that a limitation in android devices? How to do both audio and video recording in Android devices, especially using firefox?

Any info about this?  Kindly help.